# allowing another same ajax request only after the first request finished

Tags: ajax, asynchronous

I'm working with prototype.js and have the code like below..

```
            new Ajax.Request('url', {
            asynchronous: true,
            method: "get",
            onSuccess: Succeeded,
            onFailure: Error
        });
```

Problem occurs if the first requests' finishing and the next same request issued.

How can I prevent requests with same url issued unless 'Succeeded' is called?

Of course, I can fix the problem by making the change of 'asynchronous: false', but is it possible asynchronous method still applies given the situation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use asynchronous requests, as a synchronous request is rarely what you want.

I'm curious as to why the same request could be done more than once. Usually I just repeat the request in the error callback and signal success in the success callback. I use an abort timeout so I'm not waiting forever (default HTTP timeout is 2 minutes usually).

If the request is user initiated and therefore could happen more than once, you'd have to do this check manually (set an "inProgress" boolean somewhere).